# How to remove firefox 36 badge text

Tags: firefox, add-on, badge

Since firefox 36 it is possible to set badge text for a firefox add-on icon:

```
var { ToggleButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/toggle");

var button = ToggleButton({
    id: "my-button1",
    label: "my button1",
    icon: "./icon-16.png",
    onChange: changed,
    badge: 0,
    badgeColor: "#00AAAA"
  });

function changed(state) {
  button.badge = state.badge + 1;
  if (state.checked) {
    button.badgeColor = "#AA00AA";
  }
  else {
    button.badgeColor = "#00AAAA";
  }
}
```

However, it is not clear to me how to remove the badge text. Just setting its color to transparent does not work, since the text is still displayed and the background of the badge has a gradient (which is even in transparent mode visible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fully remove the badge text set it to an empty string, i.e. `button.badge = "";`